# How can i force the switch widget to only update if sertain parameters are met

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on a simple list of switches, but I don't want them to have the ability to all be switched off at the same time, is this possible to achieve, and if how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can track which switches are "on" with a `List<bool>` inside your `StatefulWidget` and take a decision to change the state of any switch according to the state of the other switches which you get from the array, something like this:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<bool> switchStates;

  @override
  void initState() {
    switchStates = List<bool>(10)..fillRange(0, 10,false);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Switch(
        value: switchStates[index],
        onChanged: (newValue){
          if(newValue)//user is trying to set switch state to true, so we don't check value of other switches as this action is always allowed
            {
            switchStates[index] = newValue;//on
            }
          else if(!newValue)//user is trying to set switch to false, so we do a check on all other switches before we turn it off
          {
            bool areAllOff = true;//suppose all are off
            for(final state in switchStates){
              if(state)//if at least one is on, so we can turn current switch off
              switchStates[index]=newValue;//off
              break;
            }
          }

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```